# Angular material: is it possible to create modals (or dialogs) with ng-template?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my project I am using [ngx-bootstrap's dialog](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) component which takes your `ng-template` and displays it as your modal.

Using `ng-template` is advantageous for many reasons and most importantly, there is no communication barrier (between modal and origin component) if `ng-template` live in same component. This way I can call my component method without any problems. For example, in following code `selectNextRow()` will change row in my table and hence `selectedRow_Session` and thus data of next row will be displayed on modal.

**app.component.ts**

```
/** display selectedRow_Session on modal */
<ng-template #sessionDetailTemplate>

      <app-session-detail-model
        [session]="selectedRow_Session"
        [bot]="bot"
        (selectNextRow)="selectNextRow()"
        (closeModel$)="modalRef.hide()"
        (selectPrevRow)="selectPrevRow()"
        [pageNumberOfCurrentRowSelected]="pageNumberOfCurrentRowSelected"
        [indexOfCurrentRowSelected]="indexOfCurrentRowSelected"
        [finalDfState]="selectedRow_Session.df_state"
        [sessionDataStore]="selectedRow_Session.data_store">
      </app-session-detail-model>

</ng-template>
```

In Angular Material Dialogs, I could only find API to that can create modals with only `Component` and not with `ng-template`.

Is there a way to do this, with or without dialogs, using Angular Material?

Comment: The API doc shows that open() accepts a TemplateRef. So yes, it's possible.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in comments, you can use a TemplateRef with @angular/material MatDialog. You can find the API reference here : [Angular Material MatDialog](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialog).

Here is a minimal example showing how to do it :

```js
    import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

    @Component({
     selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
     template: `
      <div [style.margin.px]="10">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Open Modal via Component Controller</button>
      </div>
      <div [style.margin.px]="10">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="dialog.open(myTemplate)">Open Modal directly in template</button>
      </div>

    <ng-template #myTemplate>
      <div>
        <h1>This is a template</h1>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    `
    })
    export class DialogOverviewExample {
      @ViewChild('myTemplate') customTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

      constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

      openDialog(): void {
         const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.customTemplate, {
            width: '250px'
         });

         dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
           console.log('The dialog was closed');
         });
       }
     }
```

And here is a live example using Angular v6 : [Stackblitz Live Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lej4zs?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts).

Hope it helps!